# file path cannot take the string after space

Tags: java, html, file, servlets, upload

My task is to upload a file...  For that, to download the uploaded code I need file location, for that my code has href as following:

```
out.write("<a href=\"com/UploadDownloadFileServlet?
fileName="+fileItem.getName()+"\">Download "+fileItem.getName()+"</a>");
```

but what I got in the URL portion of my browser is:

```
http://localhost:8090/FileUpload/com/com/UploadDownloadFileServlet?fileName=C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\All%20Users\Documents\My%20Pictures\Sample%20Pictures\Sunset.jpg
```

and it shows a HTTP 404 error...  Where did I go wrong?  Why does it take space as `%20`?

Comment: i think using POST request instead of GET will fix your problem , because URL will decode weather you like it or not , or decode your string back in the servlet.

Comment: Is it correct that `/com/` is there twice in the URL? That could send the browser to desert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `%20`. This is the normal way the browser encodes an URL. It is called "Percent encoding" and it is standardized here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Usually when you set a location with Javascript and you receive parameters with PHP, you don't feel the encoding and you don't have to care about. The browser takes quotas, blanks, slashes and other nasty things, it creates `%20` and else, and PHP creates the percent terms back to characters. If you don't have a feeling about this, you have to alter to the `POST` method as Vivek mentions.

There seems nothing wrong with your URL (except twice `/com/`).

I suggest you enter the URL manually to the browser and edit it step by step, entering it again and again, until the error disappears. Then see what you have changed and take the change back into your code.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
String[] command = new String[] {
    "C:" +
    File.separator + 
    "Program Files (x86)" +
    File.separator + 
    "Mozilla firefox" + 
    File.separator + 
    "firefox.exe"    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i used POST method only... and i got error because of misunderstanding the servlet name.. 
    out.write("Download "+fileItem.getName()+"");and that's all(before i included package name also). So now i cleared with space in my file path+  file name did not cause any error. Thanks Peter and vivek.